# how wcf works from end-user side not from the programmer view

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am very new to WCF and have nil knowledge about this technology or whatsoever.I just wanted to know how a client will use this. I mean suppose an application has been well-built by programmers.Now coming to deployment, do we need to deploy it on server and again do we need to install something on client machine too for successfully running the application.

or simply one needs to deploy the built system on server, that's all, and it can successfully run from any browser anywhere in world?

Answer (score 2):

[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) is a communication protocol. Two applications will use it to communicate with each other.

> WCF simplifies development of connected applications through a new service-oriented programming model. WCF supports many styles of distributed application development by providing a layered architecture. At its base, the WCF channel architecture provides asynchronous, untyped message-passing primitives. Built on top of this base are protocol facilities for secure, reliable, transacted data exchange and broad choice of transport and encoding options.

In a client/server set up, the server will have endpoints to which the clients connect. You'll find out much more about it by following the link to the MSDN.